# Ordering in django model

Tags: python, django

I have django model

```
 class TestResult(models.Model):

    chemical_name = char(50)
    value =char(50)
    unit = choices(UNIT_CHOICES)
    method = choices(METHOD_CHOICES)
    CSUSNormal = char(50)
    CSUSCaution = char(50)
```

In admin page this model consist of 180 records. Now i want to apply ordering for these records by creating field order_num. how can i set the ordering based on the order_num of each field?

I admin page i want to see all the records based on the order_num field. How can i achieve this?

Comment: That's not a django model and your variables should be lowercase

Answer (score 3):

[`Meta.ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering)

Answer (score 3):

```
class TestResult(models.Model):

    chemical_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    unit = models.CharField(choices=UNIT_CHOICES)
    method = models.CharField(METHOD_CHOICES)
    CSUSNormal = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    CSUSCaution = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    order_num=models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
       ordering=" order_num"
```

Comment: it should be noted that the it should be `ordering = ["order_num"]` . This will also allow you to do ordering based upon more than one field such as `ordering = ["order_num" ,"-value"]`